# Use a div as a submit button in JSP Servlets

Tags: java, css, jsp, html

I need a way to use a div as a submit button to send a form request to a Servlet, Or is there any other way to solve my problem. "logoutbutton" is the div.

```
<div class="logoutbutton">
     <table width="100%">
        <tr>
           <td width="50px"><img src="img/usericon.png" width="44" height="44" /></td>
           <td><a style="font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#FFF"><% out.print(session.getAttribute("userid")); %></a><br />
              <a style="font-size:20px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#FFF">Log Out</a>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No offense but this is a horrible way to provide markup for a button. If you want a submit button with a icon you can just style a actual submit button using CSS instead of embedding links into tables into divs.

Comment: Make `Log Out` a styled link.  ..Or just make it an HTML form 'button' as the user.. ..but no, wait, that's *exactly* what they'd be expecting!

Comment: This jQuery documentation could be relevant: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the your servlet which handles logout action for the link. You can do it using

```
<a href = "LogourServletUrlPattern"> Logout </a>
```

After doing this, you can logout from `doGet` method of `LogoutServet`

Comment: This is dangerous in general: what if you have a "delete" link somewhere and Google bot happens to follow it?

Comment: @llmoEuro, I would like to know in detail what you are trying to say. I am not very knowledgeable about google bot thing.

Comment: Google builds its search index using bots (programs) that visit sites and follow links on those sites. It assumes that clicking a link doesn't change anything, only displays a new page (which is the correct behaviour). Actions should be invoked using forms or AJAX.

Comment: @llmoEuro, that means all links should be idempotent? Is that the exact word ?

Comment: Yes. More on that: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html (note that links always use GET)

Answer (score 1):

I would use jquery for this and then listening for events on DOM obejcts is a peice of cake.

```
$(".logoutbutton").click(function () {
      window.location.href = 'logout.url';
});
```

or

```
$(".logoutbutton").click(function () {
      $.post( "logout.url" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's easy, use the 'onclick' event:

```
<div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="submitForm();">...</div>
```

On the onclick you can also use

```
window.location.href='LogourServletUrlPattern';
```

if you don't want to call a function and invoke the sevlet directly

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `DIV` as part of your form and submit the form on clicking on `DIV`

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function formSubmit()
{
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="frm1" action="form_action">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
<div class="logoutbutton" onclick="formSubmit()">
     <table width="100%">
        <tr>
           <td width="50px"><img src="img/usericon.png" width="44" height="44" /></td>
           <td><a style="font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#FFF"><% out.print(session.getAttribute("userid")); %></a><br />
              <a style="font-size:20px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#FFF">Log Out</a>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just given example. I have modified the answer. You can assign your servlet <url-pattern> value to action attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery for achieving this with ease.

In the DOM

```
  <div id="logout-button">Logout</div>
```

In javascript/jquery

```
$("#logout-button").click(function () {
   alert("ajax call to end session");
});
```

Even if your not using jquery you could use the above to get a round about idea on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to capture click event on the logoutbutton div and submit the form. Assuming you have a form with id 'myform':

```
<div class="logoutbutton" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit()">
```

Note that using this method the div isn't treated as a hyperlink by the browser, hence you can't do right-click-and-open-in-new-tab.

If your javascript gets complicated consider using library such as jquery.